# Jenkinsfile with docker agent not able to load ssh key

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ssh-keys

I have a simple pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:3.8-alpine3.15'
        }
    }
...
steps {
       withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "repo", keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]){
             sh '''
             set +x
             eval `ssh-agent -s`
             ssh-add ${keyfile}
             git clone git@gitlab.com/blabla
             '''

      }
   }
}
```

The errored output is:

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $keyfile
Agent pid 53
+ ssh-add **** (blabla@blabla.com)
...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I have tried the same steps with the same key step by step on the same machine and it works, the problem resides on the `withCredentials` binding. It is not viable to change to `ssh-agent` plugin.

Does anybody know what is wrong and why I can't load the credentials succesfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of debugging, what worked for me was:

- SSH Agent implementation (plugin download required, not good)

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:3.8-alpine3.15'
        }
    }
...
steps {
       sshagent(credentials: ['repo']) {
             sh '''
             set +x
             mkdir ~/.ssh
             ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
             git clone git@gitlab.com/blabla
             pip install -r requirements.txt
             '''
      }
   }
}
```

Finally I ended up using `sshagent` plugin, otherwise if you need to use `withCredentials` plugin you should consider:

- Vanilla Implementation (no extra plugin download, good)

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'python:3.8-alpine3.15'
        }
    }
...
steps {
       withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "repo", keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
             sh '''
             set +x
             mkdir ~/.ssh
             ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
             eval `ssh-agent -s`
             ssh-add ${keyfile}
             git clone git@gitlab.com/blabla
             pip install -r requirements.txt
             '''
      }
   }
}
```

Personally I consider the implementation with `withCredentials` much more approachable because you do not depend on external plugin.

External references:

- SSH Agent plugin official website: https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/
- Jenkins errors forum: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-36997
- Jenkins errors forum: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43050

With those two implementations, you should not have any problem when passing ssh keys onto a pipeline which is ran inside a docker container.

Free software.